# jQuery dynamic centering in not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center a dynamicly sized `.nav`, within a static `.container` div. I have the following code:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/8jfkv/3/)

```
 $('.nav').css({
     'position': 'fixed',
         'left': '50%',
         'top': '50%',
         'margin-left': -$(this).outerWidth() / 2,
         'margin-top': -$(this).outerHeight() / 2
 });
```

Can anyone explain why the `.nav` is not centering within its parent element?

Comment: In your JSFiddle, `this` refers to `window`, not `.nav`. If you do `$('.nav').each($(this).css(...))` then you can use `this` since it will refer to the `.nav` element.

Answer (score 3):

The primary problem is that `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does. You are still in the same scope when execution reaches these lines:

```
'margin-left': -$(this).outerWidth() / 2,
'margin-top': -$(this).outerHeight() / 2
```

so `this` still refers to what it did before the `.css` call. For the most part, `this` only changes (at jQuery's hands) when you are inside a callback to a jQuery function or event.

After fixing that, it sort of works: http://jsfiddle.net/8jfkv/11/, but there is still something off with your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:

1. As Chris pointed out, `$(this)` is not `.nav`. In your example, `$(this)` is JSFiddle's Result `iframe`, so you're calling `outerWidth/Height` on the wrong element.

   I recommend capturing `.nav` as a local variable (to minimize jQuery selections).
2. Since `.nav` is initially `position: static`, its initial width is 100% of its container. So (and assuming you already fixed #1) `outerWidth()` in your fiddle would return 500px which would lead to a left margin of -250px.

   `.nav`'s `position` needs to be set *before* you call `outerWidth()` so that its width collapses first. (And its `position` needs to be set to `absolute` instead of `fixed`.)

Both issues fixed in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jfkv/13/